# How to search for Mahabharat Book, Chapter, Verse?

Tags: mahabharata, sanskrit, translation, verse

As in, which site do I use to search Book-wise, Chapter-wise or Verse-wise?
For example, some book I'm reading on Google Books quotes Shanti Parv (which is Book 12) but mentions Verse 6930. How do I locate this Verse in other sources? I know Shanti Parv is Book 12, but how do I find/locate which Chapter of Book 12 this Verse 6930 is contained in? I'm seeing a romanized (i.e. in english) version of the Sanskrit Verse, and I want to see the original Sanskrit version of this Verse.

There seem to be different methods used for quoting by different authors/translators. There should be a common standardized way to search and quote.

[image: Screenshot from the Google Books page]

So, basically I'm now on sacred-texts.com and on the page of Book 12 Sanskrit version. How do I locate Verse 6930 when I don't know which Chapter it is in and there is no good search function on the site?

Comment: There is no verse 6930 in Śānti Parva. Most likely, it means adhyāya 69, śloka 30, within Śānti Parva. It's the fault of author of not introducing space or using a point, bar, etc. to give right numbering. We usually write it as Śānti Parva (69.30) or Śānti Parva (69:30) or Śānti Parva (69 | 30). I prefer the first format (point form), & that's what I commonly use. The numbering in Mahābhārata would be given as Mahābhārata (12.69.30), it's like pealing an onion from outside->inside, from *left->write in text*. To the left represents an outer layer, and to the right represents an inner layer.

Answer (score 2):

One way to locate a Sanskrit verse in the Mahabharata is to download [this zip file](https://gretil.sub.uni-goettingen.de/gretil/1_sanskr/2_epic/mbh/mbh1-18u.zip) from the [GRETIL website](https://gretil.sub.uni-goettingen.de/gretil.html), then search for the verse in the HTML file MBH1-18U.HTM contained inside. Since this file is huge (18 MB), you can open it in a text editor instead of browser. However, searching in browser is easier as you don't have to type the exact diacritical marks, e.g., you can search for "bhrgur uvaca" instead of "bhṛgur uvāca".

The verse in question can be found at the beginning of Shanti Parva (Book 12), Chapter 181:

12,181.001 bhṛgur uvāca 
12,181.001a asṛjad brāhmaṇān eva pūrvaṃ brahmā prajāpatiḥ 
12,181.001c ātmatejobhinirvṛttān bhāskarāgnisamaprabhān 
12,181.002a tataḥ satyaṃ ca dharmaṃ ca tapo brahma ca śāśvatam 
12,181.002c ācāraṃ caiva śaucaṃ ca svargāya vidadhe prabhuḥ 
12,181.003a devadānavagandharvadaityāsuramahoragāḥ 
12,181.003c yakṣarākṣasanāgāś ca piśācā manujās tathā 
12,181.004a brāhmaṇāḥ kṣatriyā vaiśyāḥ śūdrāś ca dvijasattama 
12,181.004c ye cānye bhūtasaṃghānāṃ saṃghās tāṃś cāpi nirmame 
12,181.005a brāhmaṇānāṃ sito varṇaḥ kṣatriyāṇāṃ tu lohitaḥ 
12,181.005c vaiśyānāṃ pītako varṇaḥ śūdrāṇām asitas tathā

You can also find the same verse on Sacred Text Archive at the link https://sacred-texts.com/hin/mbs/mbs12181.htm.

The reason you were not able to find it previously is because the Google book you are quoting from is not using a standard transliteration scheme like [IAST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Alphabet_of_Sanskrit_Transliteration). E.g., "bhṛgur uvāca" (correct IAST) is printed as "bhṛ**i**gur uvāc**h**a", "asṛjad" is printed as "asṛ**i**jad", etc.

You can find the original Sanskrit verse in Devanagari (from the Critical Edition of the Mahabharata) here:

https://archive.org/details/vwmN_the-mahabharata-shanti-parv-critically-edited-by-vishnu-s-sukhthankar-1951-bhand/page/1022/mode/2up

English translations can be found here:

- K M Ganguli: https://sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12b015.htm
- Bibek Debroy: https://archive.org/details/the-mahabharata-set-of-10-volumes/page/n2707/mode/2up

In the introduction to his translation, Bibek Debroy explains how the critical edition of Mahabharata and his own translation (which is based on the former) is organised:

https://archive.org/details/the-mahabharata-set-of-10-volumes/page/n16/mode/1up

Comment: Thank you so much for your excellent answer and all the links.